# How to skip levels in untrusted

Tags: untrusted

I progressed through level 21 and I wiped my harddrive. Is there a way of skip to a desired level so I dont have to play the levels I already beat?

Answer (score 2):

None that I know. It is cookie based, since there is no login to play [Untrusted](http://alexnisnevich.github.io/untrusted/).

Your saves across levels are not saved, but your successful answer to move to the next level is saved at [Gist Github](https://gist.github.com/). You can try searching for your answers there IMO. With luck you might find your pages with your past solutions.

But on a personal note, you can remember your solutions and try again from start. It is a fun game. Maybe this time around you can do some things differently.

Comment: Not the correct answer thought, but i really like it, try seaching other ways to complete a level, for example in my first run i added more exits in first level, in my second run i removed all the walls.

Answer (score 2):

In your browser's JavaScript console, you can enter:

```
localStorage.levelReached = [NUM];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open console (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
2. Enter: `localStorage.levelReached = NUM`
3. Reload page